# escape_javascript not working in rails 3.2.7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, escaping, rails-cells

In application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var After = 5000;
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#test").html("<%= escape_javascript(render_cell :test, :display) %>");
    }, After);
});
```

This is supposed to render the cell...But what it gives me in the browser is this: <%= escape_javascript(render_cell :test, :display) %>

Rails did not interpret the ruby part...It just gives it back as plain text...

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you mean application.js.erb?

JavaScript doesn't know ruby.

Comment: You gave me the solution...I placed it in application.js and of course  javascript doesn´t know ruby. So now it´s in application.js.erb and it works fine :) Thanks!!